# JDialogs Modal behaviour not working when used inside swingnode of javafx application

Tags: java, swing, javafx, modal-dialog

I have a full fledged Java Swing application. And now I have another Java-FX application.

I have to integrate the Swing application into the Java-FX application using `SwingNode` in Java-FX.

When I do so, everything looks fine except the modal behavior of dialogs in the Swing application is gone.

Is there any way to fix this behavior in such a type of integration?

Code snippet of my Swing Application:

```
class Solve extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static JFrame f = null;

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        f = new JFrame("frame");
        Solve s = new Solve();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("click");
        b.addActionListener(s);
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        return f;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if (s.equals("click")) {
            JDialog d = new JDialog(f, "dialog Box", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
            JLabel l = new JLabel("this is a dialog box");
            d.add(l);
            d.setSize(100, 100);
            d.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Code Snippet for my JavaFX Application:

```
public class SolveJavaFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);    
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();     
        pane.setCenter(swingNode);  
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 450));
        stage.show();
    }
    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Solve solve = new Solve();              
                swingNode.setContent((JComponent) solve.getFrame().getContentPane());
            }
        });
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean you resolved your font issue? Same issue with this question: create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Matt, I did a work around for the font issue by increasing the font sizes globally for swing application and make it alike as javafx components. I didn have any other way to do that. Now am facing this issue around dialogs.

Comment: @matt, i followed the minimal reprodcible example and have added the code snippet which has my issue posted.

Comment: Okay, so your swing node is creating a JDialog, completely oblivious to it being in a JavaFx application. What about using `Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL` is that an option?

Comment: Without Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL i dont see the modal behaviour in swing working even as a pure swing application. Only after adding that in a swing application i saw the modal behaviour.

Comment: In your example you are using `DOCUMENT_MODAL` which is different than `APPLICATION_MODAL`. Which one produces the desired results?

Comment: @matt tried with both APPLICATION_MODAL and DOCUMENT_MODAL . Both wont work.

Comment: The button doesn't show up for me when I run your javafx example. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Can you please just use your mouse and drag the window a bit. For me its showing up. Sometimes i need to drag the window a bit for it show up.

Comment: I tried a bunch, but even the most basic example with a swing node isn't working for me.

Comment: I'm pretty certain your example is not exhibiting your issue. Setting the dialog to APPLICATION_MODAL works for the swing components in the frame, which would work for the example you have pasted. I updated my answer to show an example where it doesn't work, and that is when there are javafx components also displayed in that case the fxbutton is still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is when you create your dialog,  you are using the JFrame that never gets used. Instead use `null`.

```
JDialog d = new JDialog(null, "dialog Box", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

That works for me. Notice that it is `APPLICATION_MODAL` not `DOCUMENT_MODAL`.

If I wanted to use `DOCUMENT_MODAL` then I need the correct window. I have created a utility method that might help you out.

```
Window findWindow(Container c ){
    Container p = c.getParent();
    while ( !(p instanceof Window )){
        p = p.getParent();
    }
    return (Window)p;
}
```

Now when you display your dialog.

```
        JDialog d = new JDialog(findWindow(panel), "dialog Box", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

Both of these make the dialog display, and input to the original frame does not get processed until the dialog has closed. *note in the second version you need to keep a reference to your jpanel.*

I think using `APPLICATION_MODAL` is a bit more robust. The find window should for both swing and javafx versions. On openjdk11 and openjfx11 the SwingNode didn't work at all.

This solution disables the input to the other swing components. Additional javafx components would not be disabled. In the following example the javafx button would still receive input when the dialog is showing.

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Container;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
public class SolveJavaFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);    
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();

        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
        Button but = new Button("fx button");
        but.setOnMouseClicked(evt->System.out.println("click!"));
        pane.getChildren().add(but);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 450));
        stage.show();
    }

    JPanel getPanel(){
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("click");
        b.addActionListener(evt->{
            JDialog d = new JDialog(null, "dialog Box", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JLabel l = new JLabel("this is a dialog box");
            d.add(l);
            d.setSize(100, 100);
            d.setVisible(true);
        } );
        p.add(b);
        return p;
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                swingNode.setContent( getPanel() );

        });
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, 
Using just JDialog d = new JDialog(null, "dialog Box", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); dont work for me, i dont know why.

Just to check which version of jdk you are using?

Comment: @harikrishna I used openjdk 8 on OSX. java version "1.8.0_151"

Comment: @harikrishna did you try the version where it looks up the window of the component?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for following up, am still trying it . Am trying the second approach of finding the window. But here i have a doubt. Do you return the javafx stage window from findwindow() method? javafx window is javafx.stage.window but swing window is java.awt.window and it cant be casted. So am stuck here.

Comment: Now, the find window is looking for `java.awt.Window` it searches the .parent() heirarchy until the container is a instanceof `java.awt.Window` I was considering including that import or the fully qualified name.

Comment: ok. But the ultimate parent is javax.stage.window rite?  So shouldn't we be passing that window to the dialog ? Also what is panel in findWindow(panel)? Is it Jpanel?

Comment: Yes, the panel is the JPanel. When I tried it an awt.Window was found, it is a [JLightweightFrame](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ant/8006406/javadoc.8/sun/swing/JLightweightFrame.html) which appears to be a class used for offscreen painting.

Comment: Do you also have javafx controls that you're trying to disable?

Comment: Thanks Matt, It works exactly as you said. But i was expecting the pure modal behaviour where we cant even click/focus on the parent window when the dialog is open. May be its too much to ask for :) in this kind of application. Anyway what i have is only swing components in the window and i dont have any java fx components so this should do the job. Thanks again for the help. I will post if am able to achieve pure modal behaviour in case if i can.